# Measuring temperature of fluids inside a glass tube

Tags: measurement, temperature

Suppose I have some experiment with some fluid (e.g. water or milk) flowing  through (or just residing in) a cylindrical tube made of glass.

What would be a good way to "non invasively" measure the temperature of the medium inside the glass tube (i.e. without somehow immersing a temperature sensor in the liquid?)

I could use a thermistor attached to the glass but as far as I have seen, glass is a rather bad conductor in terms of thermal energy so I suppose the measurement error would be high without waiting for a long time (until the "thermal time constant" has passed.)

Optical measurement seems to be very complex, or even impossible if I don't know the chemical properties of the medium beforehand.

Comment: Slightly offtopic comment, but *why* is this relevant? Are you trying to automate something meaning that you won't be nearby, or if you are nearby, can't you just look on the inside of the cylindrical tube for droplets caused by the vapor/steam? Or can't you touch the tube? Or.. can't you know beforehand that it is an exothermic reaction? - I'm trying to find out what your end goal is. *Perhaps* there is a better way to go about *it*. Whatever *it* is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sleeve the glass with copper that has the sensor attached.

Heat can now travel easily lengthwise down the copper to the sensor, thus the area of glass for heat to go though increases, thus reducing the thermal R from fluid to sensor. This might be sheet, or just wrapping copper foil tightly around the tube, then over the sensor for a number of turns. The conductivity of copper is 400x glass, so may be start with thickness=1/4x glass wall thickness, and length>20x wall.

Insulate the outside: accuracy is the ratio of thermal R from fluid : leakage R from ambient. (this might be a good use for a small piece of aerogel insulation)

Thermistors have very fine wire, but this should wrap around the pipe to reduce error, ie. so the wires do conduct pipe temp and don't conduct ambient temperature to the sensor.

You can the correct a leakage error by measuring ambient, but you need to watch the thermal time constants. i.e filtering of ambient sensor to match main sensor. It is better to measure part way inside the insulation for a correction sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Animals have RFID microchips under their skins. Those microchips measure today also the temperature - very useful to detect illness. A chip like that can be inside with no wires, even inside the pipe material.

Comment: For example, this one http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-RF430-TEMPSENSE from TI

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is more to keep glass in contact with the fluid then:

You can put a conventional glass thermometer inside the glass tube in the fluid, and read it optically/camera/eye from the outside.

If you are at a university, the the chemistry dept will have a glassblower who can melt a thermistor into the wall of the tube. Glass bead thermistors, and glass diode packaged thermistors, PTC (KTY81) and glass diodes could all be used. Fine platinum or nickel wire or PT100 elements could also be put in the glass. Glassblower can also let a long thin glass tube inside the main tube (sensor pocket) for a thermistor to slide into.

You can probably use a thermal IR sensor to measure the glass surface temperature if the tube diameter is large - reduces time constant but sensor accuracy is poor, and surface temp error is large because you can't insulate